# Where is ${datestamp} defined?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

In my `log4j2.xml` configuration file I notice the variable `${datestamp}` but I have no idea where this variable is defined:

```
<PatternLayout pattern="%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5level %logger{1} - %msg%n"/>
```

Please enlighten me.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html

Comment: It would help if you shared the entire configuration file, but best guess is a [property](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution)

Comment: @D.B. No it is not a property, `datestamp` is not defined anywhere in the file, only used at the quoted location.

Comment: Seems related: http://comexile.blogspot.com/2018/02/add-timestamp-to-log-file.html

Comment: What about [XInclude](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XInclude) or [Composite Configurations](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#CompositeConfiguration)? Maybe the property is defined in another file and pulled in that way?

Comment: Maybe the property is replaced at build time. Is there a maven pom or other build script that might be processing your config file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not defined anywhere. log4j2 didn't provide an error message and seems to be using a default format for displaying the date.

Comment: It must be defined somewhere, if I run a very simple vanilla project using the pattern in the question it results in "Could not instantiate FastDateFormat with pattern ${datestamp} java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"

Comment: @D.B. which version of log4j are you using? Version 2?

Comment: @D.B. I did a test by renaming datestamp to datestampXYZ and it still worked in exactly the same way.

Comment: I'm using log4j 2.12.1 - maybe the property is not found something is defaulting it, but log4j2 is not defaulting it when I don't define it in my simple project.